# Javascript: Can't access object properties from an Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, laravel

i want to know how to access object response properties from a ajax call, i'm working with laravel 5.2 and Ajax, and i have this one:

```
$.get('/provider/'+provider_id+'', function(response){ 
            console.log(response); 
});
```

[image]

Yeah i tried with `response = JSON.parse(response);`but i got this error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1(…)` what's wrong?? or how i should to do? thanks!

Comment: `var time = response.created_at;` should work

Comment: The response should already be properly formatted to JSON. You're naming your variable the same thing as one of the keys of the response apparently. So in your case, you'd need: `response.response.whichever_key`

Comment: Are you getting an error message when trying to access the properties? It looks like you may need to do `response.response.email_p` for example

Comment: `JSON.parse` expects a **string**, but `response` is already an **object**. jQuery parsed the JSON for you.

Comment: @daleyjem: You seem to confuse JSON with JavaScript objects. Sure, *the* response from the server is JSON, but the *value* of `response` is an object, not JSON.

Comment: @FelixKling ... I realize what you're trying to disqualify me for, but even ECMA-international states, "JSON objects are realized as ECMAScript objects"

Comment: @daleyjem: That doesn't make a JavaScript object a JSON object though. It only explains that this specific JSON "data type" (object) is deserialized into a JavaScript/ECMAScript object. In other languages it will be deserialized to something different (e.g. to a `dict` in Python or an instance of `stdClass` in PHP). After the JSON is deserialized you can't talk about it as JSON anymore.

Comment: @FelixKing I'll agree to disagree. I think you know what I meant, as did the people who up'd my answer twice. My goal is to answer the question with the best of my ability, not argue strict semantics. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see from the console output, `response` is already an Object. No need to parse it again.

```
$.get('/provider/' + provider_id, function(response){ 
    var data = response.response;
    console.log("Email: " + data.email_p); 
});
```